# Chaining Eloquent relation functions?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, chaining

Here is the problem:

Lets say I have 3 Eloquent models: User, Project, Task.

Each user has projects, each project has tasks. I have made my Eloquent relations so I can call for example: `$user->projects`, `$project->tasks` and so on, but I want to do a nesting.

I want to get the tasks, for the user's projects.
So I need to do something like: `$user->projects()->tasks()` and then apply a where rule (`$user->projects()->tasks()->whereSomething(1)->get()`), but it doesn't work of course. I can loop all the projects and extract the tasks manually, but I suppose there is a shorthand, which I cannot find. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$users = User::with(array('projects.tasks' => function($query)
{
    // For example I used "task_name" as a field name in tasks table
    $query->where('task_name', 'add_user');
}))->get();
```

**Update:** Code from my working project (if it helps)

```
// Model:Role (table:roles)
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Permission');
}

// Model:Permission (table:permissions)
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
}
```

There is a third (intermediate/pivot) table `permission_role` and this works:

```
$u = User::with(array('roles.permissions' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('name', 'add_user');
}))->get()->first();
print_r($u->roles[0]->permissions->first()->toArray());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => add_user
    [pivot] => Array
    (
        [role_id] => 1
        [permission_id] => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: It works, but the user's tasks are a protected property. I see them in the dump, but can't get them. If I do tasks() on the user, it gives me all his tasks, because I have such relation, but it ignores the Where.

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem but it should work, AFAIK, this is the right approach and I did this practically.